# What is std::invoke in c++?

Tags: c++, c++17

I've just been reading about `std::thread` and `std::bind` which I've faced with the `Callable` concept and `std::invoke`.

I read about `std::invoke` on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) but I didn't understand what it said. Here is my question:
What is `std::invoke`, `std::function`, `std::bind` and the `Callable` concept? And what is relationship between them?

Comment: Note `std::invoke` is C++17, not C++11.

Comment: Read cppreference for the topics again, including the examples. Answers here are unlikely to be better than the documentation and examples already available there.

Comment: check out this talk from CppCon 2015 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0

Comment: @mvrma That is a great talk.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be easily answered by simply reading the documentation that OP linked to.

Comment: @mvrma It is a great talk indeed. now I understand the difference

Comment: The std::invoke function does more than invoke functions https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220401-00/?p=106426

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`std::invoke` takes something callable, and arguments to call it with, and does the call.  `std::invoke( f, args... )` is a slight generalization of typing `f(args...)` that also handles a few additional cases.

Something callable includes a function pointer or reference, a member function pointer, an object with an `operator()`, or a pointer to member data.

In the member cases, the first argument is interpreted as the `this`.  Then remaining arguments are passed to `()` (except in the pointer-to-member-data-case), with `std::reference_wrapper`s unwrapping.

INVOKE was a concept in the C++ standard; C++17 simply exposed a `std::invoke` which does it directly.  I suspect it was exposed partly because it is useful when doing other metaprogramming, partly because every standard library has an implementation of INVOKE in it already and exposing it was basically free, and partly because it makes talking about INVOKE easier when it is a concrete thing.

Comment: Note that `std::invoke` is not `constexpr`.

Comment: @Yakk thanks. I think i was confused INVOKE concept with `std::invoke`. and if I understand correctly, INVOKE concept is used in `std::bind`, `std::thread`. right?

Comment: @user3397145 I still don't understand why is this in all capitals letter like no other thing in the C++ documentation.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Hi, I am from the future. `std::invoke` is `constexpr` as of c++20.

Answer (score 17):

A `Callable` object is, apart from C++-specific details, "something that can be called". It need not be a function: C++ has a number of types that can be called, and going through them every time where any could show up (read: generic code) is problematic and too repetitive.

That's what `std::invoke` is for - it allows a generic object that can be called (which, according to C++17, satisfies the `Callable` concept) to be invoked effortlessly.

Let's consider a simple example:

```
void foo() { std::cout << "hello world\n"; };

template <bool b>
struct optionally_callable
{
        std::enable_if_t<b> operator() ()  {   std::cout << "hi again\n";   }
};

int main()
{
    auto c = [] { std::cout << "hi from lambda\n" ;};

    std::invoke(foo);
    std::invoke(c);

    auto o = optionally_callable<true>{};
    //auto o2 = optionally_callable<false>{};

    std::invoke(o);

}
```

`o2` is **not** callable, that is, `std::is_invocable<decltype(o2)>::value` is `false`.

Comment: Points for improvement would be?

Comment: Explain why this is better then writing `foo()`, `c()` and `o()`

Comment: @Baruch, https://youtu.be/zt7ThwVfap0?t=655

Comment: @Baruch although it's a bad idea to do. If you have a map of `std::functions<void()>` it is more clear to write `std::invoke(funcs.at(key))` than it is to do `funcs.at(key)()`.