# How to use void parameter when using template in C++

Tags: c++

I want to make a function to test the running time of the incoming function.
I use templates to make it applicable to many functions.

I omitted the code for counting time.
like this:

```
template<typename F>
void get_run_time(F func)
{
//time start
 func;
//time end
}
```

But if a function I pass in is `void`, an error will be report and prompt me to add `F=void`.
I tried to add it, but it didn't work. I can change void to bool, but it's very strange.

Another problem is that I want to test a function time and run my whole code normally .So I increased the return value.
like this:

```
template<typename F>
F get_run_time(F func)
{
//time start
 F tf=func;
//time end
 return tf;
}
```

But the actual test time is obviously wrong. I guess it starts to run the function when it return .How can it get the running results before continuing with the following code?

Comment: you're not calling the function

Comment: I didn't use (), but it still works Why?

Comment: @jerx Because `func;` without the `()` has no effect.

Comment: @jerx referring to a function by its name simply produces a pointer to the function. So your statement `func;` is effectively a no-op, it just evaluates the value of that pointer (the address of the function being pointed at) and then ignores the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to call the passed function to actually time its execution. Note, in your code you do not call it, using the `()` call operator:

```
template <typename Func>
void timer1 (Func func)
{
    // start timer
    func(); 
    // stop timer
}
```

Second, note these nuances:

```
// Will take the same time as the timer1
template <typename Func>
Func timer2 (Func func1)
{
    // func2 is a copy of func1
    // This copying won't increase the time as you thought it will
    Func func2 = func1;
    // You still need to call the function
    func2();

    // Returns pointer to function
    return func2;
}

void foo() { std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; }

int main() {
    // Func, here, is a type void (*)()
    // Prints "foo()"
    timer2(foo);    
}
```

Third, you may want to look toward this approach:

```
// Since C++14
auto timer3 = [](auto&& func, auto&&... args)
{
    // start timer

    // Forward the func and invoke the call operator
    // with however many forwarded arguments passed to the timer3
    std::forward<decltype(func)>(func)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);

    // stop timer
};

void foo(int, int) {}

int main() 
{
    timer3(foo, 21, 42);    
}
```

---

Even more proper and concise way to do the job, as noted by the [@JHBonarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6717178), is to use the [`std::invoke`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680182/what-is-stdinvoke-in-c) (since C++17), which was covered in this thread: [What is std::invoke in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680182/what-is-stdinvoke-in-c)

Comment: Note the existence of `std::invoke`. The cpp reference page also has good explication

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic C++ way (as I see it) is this

```
template <class F>
auto call(F f)
{
  Timer t;
  return f();
}
```

This works with functions returning void. Note, no start and stop here. `Timer` is a RAII class that starts the timer on construction and stops on destruction.

Forwarding parameters to `f` and niceties like `std::invoke` are not shown for brevity.

Comment: I'm wondering, isn't this one of the few cases where `decltype(auto)` can/should be used as a return type, in order to perfectly forward it?

Comment: @JHBonarius frankly I never understood it

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  with `auto` we invoke the type deduction, and with the `decltype` we introduce the `decltype` rules for the deduction. So, the `call` will return exactly the type that the `f` returns.

Comment: @rawrex we also can use original `auto call(F f) -> type-id` syntax with `std::invoke_result_t<F, arg-types...>` as type-id which would be invariant of call's code, not relying on the return statement